# upload data from github

Tags: r, data.table

Hello Community,

```
jhu_cases <- as.data.frame(data.table::fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv"))
```

I tired also

```
jhu_cases <- as.data.frame(data.table::fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv",
                                         header = TRUE, sep = ",", sep2 = "/"))
```

seems doesnt work,
many thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide an error message so the community is better able to help you out. Are you sure that you have installed `data.table`? Both of your examples work in my session with no errors.

Comment: Alternatively, `read.csv` works fine as well. `read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv", check.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, it's because they've changed the names of the csv., solved this way:

```html
#traer datos de john hopkins
Main<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series"


#guardar los links a varios CSV separados
confirmed_Path <- file.path(Main, "time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv")
death_Path <- file.path(Main, "time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv")
recovered_Path <- file.path(Main, "time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv")

#leer los datos incluidos en cada csv
ConfirmedData <- read.csv(confirmed_Path, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DeathData <- read.csv(death_Path, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
RecoveredData <- read.csv(recovered_Path, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```